# Creating View + Query (Combining columns + adding an extra attribute)

Tags: sql, view

I managed to solve it using UNION between two querys, I belive my attempt was a little off and tried to do a mathematical add. This is problaby not the best way you can do it, but it worked and that's enough for me. Thank you for your help.

Working solution:

```
CREATE VIEW Registrations AS
(SELECT S.identificationnumber AS StudentId, S.name AS StudentName, C.code AS CourseCode, C.name AS CourseName, 'Waiting' AS Status
FROM  Waitinglist W, Student S, Course C
WHERE S.identificationnumber = W.identificationnumber
AND W.code = C.code) UNION (SELECT S.identificationnumber AS StudentId, S.name AS StudentName, C.code AS CourseCode, C.name AS CourseName, 'Registered' AS Status
FROM  Registeredat R, Student S, Course C
WHERE S.identificationnumber = R.identificationnumber
AND R.code = C.code);
```

---

Origianl Problem:

I'm a begginner at databases and SQL, so things might not look that professional.

What I'm trying to do in plain text:
*I'm trying to create a view for all registerd and waiting students, for all courses. I also want to add a new "column" thats either "registerd" or "waiting".*

How I want the view to look:

```
StudentID, StudentName, CourseCode, CourseName, Status

StudentID = Combined idenficationnumber for Table "RegisterdAt" and "Waitinglist"
StudentName = Based on StudentID find matching name in Table "Student"
CourseCode = Combined code for Table "RegisterdAt" and "Waitinglist"
CourseName = based on code find matching name in Table "Course"
Status = Either "registered" or "waiting" 
   depending on if we got the "row" from Table "RegisterdAt" or "Waitinglist"
```

The Created Tables(I have also added some examplery data into them, for easier testing):

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
identificationnumber  VARCHAR(20),
name VARCHAR(50),
branchname VARCHAR(50),
programmename VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(identificationnumber),
FOREIGN KEY(branchname, programmename) REFERENCES Branch(name, programmename)
);

CREATE TABLE Course(
code CHAR(6),
name VARCHAR(50),
credits VARCHAR(10),
departmentname VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(code),
FOREIGN KEY(departmentname) REFERENCES Department(name)
);

CREATE TABLE Waitinglist(
identificationnumber VARCHAR(20),
code CHAR(6),
ddate VARCHAR(10),
PRIMARY KEY(identificationnumber, code),
FOREIGN KEY(identificationnumber) REFERENCES Student(identificationnumber),
FOREIGN KEY(code) REFERENCES Course_with_maxstudents(code)
);

CREATE TABLE Registeredat(
identificationnumber VARCHAR(20),
code CHAR(6),
PRIMARY KEY(identificationnumber,code),
FOREIGN KEY(identificationnumber) REFERENCES Student(identificationnumber),
FOREIGN KEY(code) REFERENCES Course(code)
);
```

An attempt to create a view(not working, and missing registerd/waiting attribute):

```
CREATE VIEW Registrations AS
SELECT (R.identificationnumber + W.identificationnumber) AS StudentId, S.name AS StudentName, (R.code + W.code) AS CourseCode, C.name as CourseName
FROM  Registeredat R, Waitinglist W, Student S, Course C
WHERE S.identificationnumber = (R.identificationnumber + W.identificationnumber)
AND C.code = (R.code + W.code);
```

Comment: When I enter your `create table`s and `create view` into [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c307), there's no complaint.

Comment: The tables should work, the "create view" wont work for me though. But I haven't tried using "SQL Fiddle". But if you get the view to work, do you know how to add an extra column "Status" to the view: being either "registered" or "waiting" depending on if we got the "row" from Table "RegisterdAt" or "Waitinglist"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working solution you posted looks great. I would just make the plain UNION into a UNION ALL, for it seems unlikely for you to need to remove duplicates from between these 2 subqueries. The ALL will prevent the server from doing unnecessary work to resort the combined results and search for non-existant duplicates.

So it would become:

```
CREATE VIEW Registrations AS  
(
    SELECT S.identificationnumber AS StudentId, S.name AS StudentName, C.code AS CourseCode, C.name AS CourseName, 'Waiting' AS Status  
    FROM  Waitinglist W, Student S, Course C  
    WHERE S.identificationnumber = W.identificationnumber  
    AND W.code = C.code  
)  
UNION ALL  
(  
    SELECT S.identificationnumber AS StudentId, S.name AS StudentName, C.code AS CourseCode, C.name AS CourseName, 'Registered' AS Status  
    FROM  Registeredat R, Student S, Course C  
    WHERE S.identificationnumber = R.identificationnumber  
    AND R.code = C.code  
);
```

Comment: Thank you, didnt even know there was a "UNION ALL" :)

Answer (score 0):

Add column status "registered" depending on r.code being not null, otherwise "waiting"

```
CREATE VIEW Registrations AS
SELECT (R.identificationnumber + W.identificationnumber) AS StudentId,
       S.name AS StudentName,
       (R.code + W.code) AS CourseCode,
       C.name as CourseName,
       case when r.code is not null then 'registered' else 'waiting' end as status
FROM  Registeredat R, Waitinglist W, Student S, Course C
WHERE S.identificationnumber = (R.identificationnumber + W.identificationnumber)
AND C.code = (R.code + W.code);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e70ff) for further testing.

I dropped the foreign key constraints, because the various tables aren't defined here.

Comment: Didnt manage to solve it using this way, but I took a different approach and got it working, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Pro9 And how looks your solution?